# Notification endpoint validation not working with Laravel Endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph and I need to set up a webhook to receive changes to email and calendar events. I was able to get it working with my PHP Laravel application, but now that I am trying to subscribe to notifications, I am running into issues with validating the `notificationUrl`, which is pointing to a public server of mine.

The script for creating the webhook is returning the following error:

```
Client error: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: 
{ 
  "error": { 
     "code": "InvalidRequest", 
     "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Response must ex (truncated...)
```

The truncated part I believe is

> Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.

Here is my code for creating the subscription:

```
$data = [
    "changeType" => "created",
    "notificationUrl" => "https://anatbanielmethod.successengine.net/office365/webhooks/events",
    "resource" => "me/events",
    "expirationDateTime" => "2018-12-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState" => "secret",
];

$result = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/subscriptions')
    ->attachBody($data)
    ->execute();
```

and here is my method for my `notificationUrl`:

```
public function events()
{
    //if validationToken exists return that to validate notificationUrl
    if(isset($_REQUEST['validationToken'])){
        return response($_REQUEST['validationToken'], 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }

    //process event normally for those that have already been validated
}
```

Once again this URL is [public and live](https://anatbanielmethod.successengine.net/office365/webhooks/events) and I have tested it by using Postman to send it test posts and it is working fine. Also, I added this route to my `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware to allow a third party post to hit this URL.

Originally I set up a simple single page PHP script to test validating the `notificationUrl` and that simple script worked fine. It successfully validates Webhooks created that point to it. Here is that one page script code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['validationToken'])){
        echo $_REQUEST['validationToken']; // needed only once when subscribing
    } else {
      //process like normal not a validation Token request...
        }
    }
```

So I would expect that the Laravel endpoint would work like the simple one page PHP script, and it is when I test both URLs in Postman, but the Laravel endpoint is not validating when Office365 attempts to validate it when creating a new webhook.

I have searched all over for help on this and read through all of the Microsoft developer documentation I can find on webhooks and these are some of the more helpful parts of the documentation but I am still not finding an answer to this issue:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Any ideas of this?

Comment: You're sending back the validation token but it's adding a linefeed in the body prior to the response. I don't see where that is coming from based on the code here but you may want to try trimming the token before sending it back.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Marc! You were correct about the linefeed being the issue, I am still not sure where the line feed is coming from, some how Laravel appears to be adding it. Needless to say I found a solution by adding an "ob_clean();" right before returning the response. Below is my updated notificationUrl method:

```
public function events()
{
    //if validationToken exists return that to validate notificationUrl
    if(isset($_REQUEST['validationToken'])){

      ob_clean();//this line is cleaning out that previously added linefeed

      return response($_REQUEST['validationToken'], 200)
          ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }

    //process event normally for those that have already been validated
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's odd that JakeD's answer requires the use of ob_clean(). here is my webhook controller method in my Laravel 5.7.x app:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function webhook (Request $request) {
    if (filled($request->input('validationToken'))) {
        return response($request->input('validationToken'))
                ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }


    // code to process the webhook after validation is complete
}
```

I don't see an extra linefeed character and the Microsoft Graph API subscription is validated and created.